# What is the gram­mat­i­cal term for “‑ed” words like these?

Tags: single-word-requests, syntactic-analysis, parts-of-speech, inflectional-morphology, grammatical-roles

In English we say things like:

- a *cal­i­brat**ed*** de­vice
- a *dis­trib­ut**ed*** prod­uct
- a *found**ed*** com­pany
- a *de­stroy**ed*** house

Those *‑ed* words there all sig­nify that some verb (here re­spec­tively *cal­i­brate, dis­tribute, found,* or *de­stroy*) has been “done onto” 
the noun that fol­lows it.   What is the term for this gram­mat­i­cal de­vice? Or, what is a sin­gle term for some­thing **hav­ing *been done* unto *X*** as a 
char­ac­ter­is­tic of that *X*?

As­sum­ing that we’re talk­ing only about words that de­rive from verbs and used with nouns 
here like my ex­am­ples all do, can that gram­mat­i­cal term you’ve cho­sen
**also** be ap­plied to any sorts of words that **do not** end in *‑ed*,
and are there any sorts of words that **do** end in *‑ed* which this
gram­mat­i­cal term would **not** ap­ply equally to?

Comment: @user22542, "to run" or "to jump" is also an "action", but it is not something that is "done onto a NOUN".

Comment: I’m not entirely sure what you’re asking here. What ‘device’ are you referring to, exactly? The words you highlight are all **adjectives**, more specifically **past participles** of verbs. Is that what you’re looking for (because if so, I’d say that was off-topic here as being easily findable in general references)? If not, please edit your question to make it clearer what exactly it is you’re after.

Comment: Alas, when a verb form, eg, functions as an adjective there are a dozen different terms used to describe it, most more confusing than elucidating.

Comment: Reminder to everyone: answer in answers, not in comments. Comments are for asking for clarification or suggesting improvements to the question.

Answer (score 14):

They are called the Past Participle.
They can either be formed by adding the suffix *ed*

or be an irregular such as: *eat*-> *eaten* -> *fight* -> *fought* (not to be confused with The Past Simple which is simply the verb of past simple tenses clauses.

They can be many things in English.

just to name a few:

- an adjective
- the perfect module verbs
- passive voice

Comment: What’s a “perfect module verb”?

Comment: Though '-ed forms' are traditionally termed 'Past Participles' they have nothing to do with Grammar Tenses. That's why I would call them 'Passive Participles'.

Comment: @user307254 Also, past participles do not have anything to do with passive voice, necessarily, as in *I have seen it.*. In addition the term "passive participle" is not really common.

Comment: @RMac Did you misinterpret my comment?

Comment: @rexkogitans Yes, I did. It was the first word "also" and my toddler distracting me that did it. :) Apologies, I will delete my comment. But I do agree with you that "perfect participle" is not a good term due to its rarity and also inaccuracy. "Perfect" is a word used to describe other things in grammar, and it doesn't make sense to use it here.

Comment: @user307254- I agree with you that 'passive' and 'active' better describe the participles than 'past' and 'present', even though the passive participle is also used with (past or present) perfect constructions.  When used as adjectives, the meaning of a participle is passive or active, as in "the fallen apple" and "the falling apple" (although rexkogitans might argue about "the spoiled apple" being equivalent to "the apple that spoiled [itself]").

Comment: "past participle" as in *I have seen it* in opposite to "present participle" as in *I am seeing it*. Both sentences are active. And it is called "participle", which has something to do with "part"; so the verb-form is not itself a fully functioning verb form like present tense or past tense, but a part of it.

Answer (score 3):

The *-ed* in all of your examples is a past-participle suffix. A past participle is not a **derived** form: rather, it is an **inflected** form of a verb (assuming you accept the distinction between derivation and inflection as grammatical processes in English). Most past participles end in *-ed,* but some end in *-⁠(e)n* instead (like *beaten*) and some don't end in either *-ed* or *-(e)n* (like *stood* or *hurt*). The past participle can have a passive meaning, so it can also be called a "passive participle". In the context of English, "past participle" and "passive participle" refer to the same verb form.

But not all words ending in *-ed* are verb forms. Words belonging to other parts of speech can be derived from past participles. I think the most common type of derivation is past participle → adjective. Since verbs and adjectives are distinct parts of speech, it's best not to refer to such adjectives as "participles": instead, they can be called *departicipial adjectives* (a synonymous term is "participial adjectives"), which lets us reserve the term *participle* for the inflected form of the verb. That said, it's not always possible to figure out whether a word is a participle or a departicipial adjective.

Here are some common texts for finding out whether a word is an adjective or a verb:

- Can it be preceded by *very*? If so, it's an adjective. This test doesn't give positive results for me for any of your phrases. (But note that this test only works one way: it can't tell you that a word *isn't* an adjective. There are some adjectives that can't be preceded by *very*.)
- Can it be preceded by *carefully*? If so, it's a verb. For me, this test indicates that the *-ed* words in all of your examples could be verbs.
- Can you add the prefix *un-* (with the sense of "not", not with a sense of reversal)? If so, it's probably an adjective. For me, this test indicates that *calibrated* at least can be an adjective (since we certainly can say "an uncalibrated device"). The situation is less clear for *distributed, destroyed* and *founded.* There are dictionary entries for *[undistributed](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/undistributed)* and *[undestroyed](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/undestroyed)*, but "an undistributed product" and "an undestroyed house" both sound a bit weird to me. *Unfounded* clearly exists as the negation of a different sense of the word *founded,* but *"an unfounded com­pany" doesn't seem acceptable to me.

There are other possible tests, but I can't describe all of them. Some sources suggest that word order might be relevant, but I believe this is a mistaken view, so I haven't included this as a test.

I think I've made it clear from what I've said above that there are many words ending in *-ed* that are not past participles/passive participles. (Most obviously, many past-tense verb forms end in *-ed,* but they are definitely not participles.)

Comment: Right: ideas can be unfounded, but probably not companies.

Comment: This is a very good answer. At the risk of making things harder than they need be, I cannot help but wonder whether it also applies to such things as hard-boiled eggs with hard-set egg yolks, hard-bound books, hand-drawn illustrations, horse-drawn carriages, hard-handed despots, hard-bitten veterans, hard-nosed detectives, hard-hearted lovers, hard-fought battles, hard-won victories, and ill-gotten gains.

Comment: I though the word "participle" *meant* "verb form used as an adjective"; in my understanding, the "-ing" form of a verb can be referred to as a participle or a gerund, depending on whether it's used as a verb or a noun.

Comment: @NoName: Terminology in this area is a bit confusing. A verb in participle form can be said to be "used as an adjective", in that it can appear in many of the same contexts as an adjective (for example, after a form of "to be"). But many linguists would say that a verb does not *become* an adjective just by being used this way.

Comment: @NoName: Likewise, there is a distinction between *-ing* forms that are verbs "used as nouns", e.g. in contexts like "Carefully building relationships is an important element of success" ("building" here would traditionally be called a gerund) and *-ing* forms that actually are nouns, such as "building" in "The careful building of relationships is an important element of success" (this type of noun can be called a "gerundial noun"; see my question here: [Is “programming” not a noun?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/307865/is-programming-not-a-noun)).

Comment: Ah that makes sense, thanks for the example.

Answer (score 2):

In English, a verb that is used as an adjective to describe a noun is called a [participle](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/grammar/participles). See UhtredRagnarsson's answer.

> A participle is a word formed from a verb, usually by adding -d, -ed, or -ing.
>
> There are two kinds of participle in English, as follows:
>
> The present participle
>
> [...]
>
> The past participle
>
> Participles are used [...] as adjectives.

[see article for other uses]

There is, however, a different term used to describe verbs when the action of the verb is performed on/to/at/etc. something. That term is [*transitive verb*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/grammar/transitive-and-intransitive-verbs).

> transitive verb is one that is used with an object: a noun, phrase, or pronoun that refers to the person or thing that is affected by the action of the verb. In the following sentences, admire, maintain, face, and love are transitive verbs:
>
> I admire your courage.
>
> We need to maintain product quality.
>
> I couldn’t face him today.
>
> She loves animals.

Comment: It's worth noting that transitive verbs are often made into past participles, like in the examples given in the question. Those are still past participles. There is no word to differentiate transitive participles from intransitive participles or from transitive verbs used where the object of the verb is not relevant to the meaning the participle is used to convey (and therefore is omitted from the use of the participle).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the tense of the verb is the point of your question. I suppose a simple answer is they are "**actions**" as verbs, but thank you for the additional input in the comments. More specifically, they are "***objective actions***", or you might possibly consider "***operative actions***" as well (*because they are exerting force or influence on something*).

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/objective

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/operative

Answer (score -1):

This is really simple. It does not need a whole note for explanation.

The *"ed"* is grammatically referred as **the past tense marker** ...... *the past participle*

However, don't be confused when the *past tense marker* is added to a *verb* to perform the function of an Adjective.

For instance,

1. A **distributed** products
2. A **designed** artifact
3. The **faded** car

Comment: Simple past tense and past participle serve very different purposes in a sentence. Simple past tense is used to show the verb happened in the past, while past participle is the verb form that acts as an adjective (being something that happened to the modified noun in the past). Also, the phrase "past tense marker" is not used to reference the "-ed" suffix because irregular verbs (e.g., "break" / "broke" / "broken") do not match that pattern.

Comment: All right, perfectly perfect. However, I meant this past tense marker "-ed" is attached to regular verbs. Hence, the past participles perform the functions of an Adjective.